# Why would Postgres objects lose order occasionally in production by id, and how can I fix them/prevent it from happening again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm running Rails 4 with Postgres on Puma in Heroku, and the objects in a model seem to occasionaly get mixed around in creation.

In general, for example, the first object in a call to Post.all has an id of 1, and the 100th object has an id of 100.

However, although the approximate order is maintained. Currently the objects near the end have the order of ID as an example: [66,67,68,69,70,72,73,75,58,59,60,63,65,71,74] and the created_at ordering is just as screwy, as it matches the ids.

What causes such nonsense? And is there a way to from the console reorder these objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the order:

`Post.order(:created_at)`

`Post.all` *does not* guarantee any order unless you've defined a default scope. You can do that like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(:created_at) }
end
```

Now a call to `Post.all` returns your posts ordered by `created_at`, thus your IDs should be in order.

Comment: Thanks, that default scope makes my life a lot easier

Comment: `.order(id: :asc)` commenting this back in for myself or anyone else which you included initially, as a potentially useful trick in another circumstance.

Comment: I wonder for speed if order by :created_at or id: :asc is faster. Maybe if I look into adding an index they're equal speed?

Comment: Since `id` is a primary key, a unique index is added automatically. If you want to order by `created_at`, you should create an index for it.

Comment: If you're not modifying `created_at` (which you shouldn't), and you want the results ordered by their creation, just order by id.

Comment: `.order(:id)` is equivalent to `.order(id: :asc)`; if you want to order by descending, then `.order(id: :desc)`.

Comment: Oh cool, that's sort of what I thought. I'm just going to use `default_scope { order(:id) }` then. Thanks you :)